# make>> /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Numerical result out of range

Tags: gcc, makefile

My previous code was compiling fine but a recent upgrade messed up something and when I run make I get the following error on a simple example.

```
make
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Numerical result out of range
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [SimpleExample] Error 1
```

The example code basically does nothing, it just prints "hello". 
Anyone aware of this issue?? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have encountered this issue a few times. Every single time it had something to do with the build happening on an NTFS or network filesystem. Moving the build directory to a proper Unix FS (e.g. ext3/4) fixed the issue.

We cannot help you more, unless you provide additional information, such as your platform, programming language and perhaps some sample code that reproduces this issue on your system.

Comment: awesome!.. that is exactly the problem in my case. i had my repositories on a NTFS partition.

Comment: @sodium: you're welcome! Would you mind mentioning your operating system (vendor, version and kernel version, if applicable), as well as how you mount the NTFS partition?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 10.04 and my NTFS partition was mounted directly by Ubuntu. I have two hard drives one with windows XP and the other with windows 7 and Ubuntu